# Sampling from a lognormal distribution

Tags: sampling, random-generation, lognormal-distribution

Suppose we are given $\mu$ and $\sigma$ for a lognormal distribution with random variable $X$.  $\mu$ is the mean of the variable's logarithm and $\sigma$ is the standard deviation of the variable's logarithm.  Then if $Z$ is sampled from a standard normal distribution ($Z$ has mean 0 and std deviation 1),

$$X = e^{\mu + \sigma Z}$$

Now, I am given access to a uniform random generator, and use Box-Muller to generate a sample $Z$, can I generate a sample from $X$ by applying the above formula, or will there be issues with doing this?

Comment: Yes, that should work fine

Comment: Yes. You're generating GBM? Correct.

Answer (score 6):

X is log-normal means log X is normal. Since the exponential is a monotone-transformation if you correctly sample Z, you will correctly sample X so yes, the method you suggested works